# /YYYY/MM/Title-Slug URL structure with Friendly_Id Solution Chokes on #new and #edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a partial solution to my [previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361331/implementing-yyyy-mm-title-slug-url-structure-with-friendly-id) which is correctly displaying the posts#index and posts#show routes, but is choking after creating a post:

> **ActionController::UrlGenerationError in PostsController#create**
>   No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id, :month, :year]
>
> Extracted source (around line #32):
>   30    respond_to do |format|
>   31      if @post.save
>   32        format.html { redirect_to post_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
>   33        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
>   34      else
>   35        format.html { render :new }

…and editing a post:

> No route matches [PATCH] "/blog/example-post/blog/2015/09/example-post"

Here are all the files in question (working off the same very simple scaffolded blog):

```
$ rails new blog
[...]
$ cd blog
# (Add friendly_id to Gemfile & install)
$ rails generate friendly_id
$ rails generate scaffold post title content slug:string:uniq
[...]
$ rake db:migrate
```

### routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope 'blog' do
    get     '',                   to: 'posts#index',  as: 'posts'
    post    '',                   to: 'posts#create'
    get     '/new',               to: 'posts#new',    as: 'new_post'
    get     '/:id/edit',          to: 'posts#edit',   as: 'edit_post'
    get     '/:year/:month/:id',  to: 'posts#show',   as: 'post'
    patch   '/:id',               to: 'posts#update'
    put     '/:id',               to: 'posts#update'
    delete  '/:year/:month/:id',  to: 'posts#destroy'
  end
end
```

### post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  def year
    created_at.localtime.strftime("%Y")
  end

  def month
    created_at.localtime.strftime("%m")
  end
end
```

### posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def edit
    @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to post_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to post_path, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :slug)
    end
  end
end
```

### posts_helper.rb

```
module PostsHelper

  def post_path(post)
    "blog/#{post.year}/#{post.month}/#{post.slug}"
  end

end
```

### app/views/posts/index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Listing Posts</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Slug</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.title %></td>
      <td><%= post.content %></td>
      <td><%= post.slug %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', post_path(post) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Post', new_post_path %>
```

In summary, here's what works:

- /blog/index
- /blog/2015/09/example-post
- Creating a new post (up until the point where it's supposed to redirect to posts#show when you get the UrlGenerationError mentioned above)

  - That said, the new post is added to the DB so if you go back to /index the new post will be visible
- Destroying a post

…What doesn't work:

- Editing a post (the edit page with the form will render, but after submitting your changes you'll get the aforementioned error - and the changes never make it to the DB)
- Completing the redirect after creating a new post (mentioned earlier).
- /blog/2015/index
- /blog/2015/09/index

I'm stoked that I've gotten this far - any guidance to resolving these outstanding issues would be really appreciated!

**EDIT**

With thanks to @brad-werth, post creation has been fixed with the following change:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post.year, @post.month, @post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
```

I've also tried resolving the post edit problem in the following way:

Changed the edit route to `get '/:year/:month/:id/edit', to: 'posts#edit', as: 'edit_post'` and added the following override to posts_helper.rb to keep the index page from breaking:

```
  def edit_post_path(post)
    "#{post.year}/#{post.month}/#{post.slug}/edit"
  end
```

And now the "edit" link from the index page is going to the correct URL (`/blog/2015/09/example-post/edit` - it used to go to `/blog/example-post/edit`) and successfully renders the edit page. But this results in PATCH breaking (indeed, the updates don't make it to the DB):

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/blog/2015/09/example-post/blog/2015/09/example-post"
```

I recognize that this duplication problem likely lies with this edit_post_path override, but the following attempts to force the correct PATCH route have no effect:

1. Update PATCH route to `patch '/:year/:month/:id', to: 'posts#update'`
2. Name the updated PATCH route to `as: 'patch'` and add PATCH path override to posts_helper:

   ```
   def patch_path(post)
     "#{post.year}/#{post.month}/#{post.slug}"
   end
   ```
3. Change the override to:

   ```
   def patch_path(post)
     ""
   end
   ```
4. Un-name & change PATCH route to `patch '', to: 'posts#update'`

Looking at the posts_controller, it doesn't look like the problem is there since it's not the redirect is not the problem - and I don't see why `@post.update(post_params)` would be problematic:

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So as far as I can tell the duplication in the URL is happening prior to the PATCH action, which brings us back to the EDIT flow - it must be passing the duplication to PATCH where it winds up choking. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error states:

`No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts"} missing required keys: [:id, :month, :year]`

As you can see from your failing line, `format.html { redirect_to post_path, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }`, you are calling `post_path` with no arguments.

Your route `get     '/:year/:month/:id',  to: 'posts#show',   as: 'post'` expects a year, month, and id. This jives with your error message above.

To fix, simply supply the missing parameters, like so:

`format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post.year, @post.month, @post), notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }`

Comment: I just noticed you have a helper named post_path. This is overriding your route, maybe on purpose. You need to pull it, or call it like `post_path(@post)`. Defining methods that overlap route helpers might not be a great plan, for maintainability.

Comment: Your patch error is the same basic thing, note that your route is only expecting the id, not everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @brad-werth. Passing in the missing params into the 'create' redirect worked. Unfortunately, the 'update' is still failing with the same change.

Comment: As for pulling the routing override, as far as I can tell this is the only way to get the /YYYY/MM/slug URL structure to work. If you know of an alternative way that is better for maintainability, I'd be happy to go that way.

Comment: @BrianM. I address the update bit in the comments. It would really be better as a separate question, but I think you have enough information to  solve this one. I'd rather help you learn than spoon feed you a solution. Look at the route you are targeting, it only has the id parameter. You either need to build it out, or adjust the named route parameters...

Comment: I appreciate you wanting to help me help myself (that's what I want too, but sometimes you get a little anxious when you've been hitting your head against the wall on the same problem for hours ;-) ). I've updated the original question to outline my attempts to resolve the edit problem.

Comment: @BrianM. I'm not sure updating the original question is the best way to get a solution. The original question was about a specific error. It also mentioned another error, but without detail. You have replaced the original detail with the heretofore absent details regarding the second issue. I feel like these would have been better as very specific separate questions. I am not inclined to answer questions that evolve over the course of several days. These questions are usually not useful to others, and are frustrating to answerers. I'm afraid I do not have any more time to invest into this one.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: With all due respect @brad-werth, the original question had two errors; the first of which you've helped me resolve (thanks!). Consequently, I don't believe this to be a case of a "chameleon question" if I'm updating what I'm trying to resolve the second error based on your guidance. That said, I can appreciate your position about having the question addressing one error and not two. I had assumed (yes, I acknowledge the "assume" saying) that since it applied to the same source desire that it made sense to include them both. I appreciate the time and help you've shared - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in update and create actions change:

```
format.html { redirect_to post_path, notice: 'Post was successfully ...' }
```

with

```
format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully ...' }
```